# How to move an object up and down like a wave?

Tags: mathematics, matrix

I am trying to move my object up and down using `cos` and `sin`, but I have problem understanding how does the `sin` and `cos` work, so I can make my object move up and down like a wave frequently

Init Time starts from value of 16.00  it keeps on increment up to 17.065

```
initTime += msec * 0.001;
float x  =  cos(initTime* 2.46) * 2075;
float y  =  sin (initTime* 2.888) * 200;
```

My object goes down and up, then goes back to its initial position, then goes up and down once again, I want it to be like a wave

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I still think you need to understand [basic trigonometry](http://www.trigonometry-help.net/basictrigonometry.php). But here is a simple introduction of how to use `sin` and `cos` to simulate a wave.

The basic wave formula is:

> f(t) = *A* * sin( 2 * pi * *f* * *t* + *phase* )

Where:

> - ***f*** is the **frequency**, which controls the number of times the waves    repeats per unit time, *f* = 1/*P* where *P* is the number of periods.
> - ***A*** is the **amplitude** of the wave, which represents the highest and    lowest points of the wave.
> - **2*pi** is a **scaling factor** to be able to deal with the equation in    terms of frequency and periods. (in other words, make it easier
>     and    more intuitive).
> - ***t*** is a parameter that represents time, or any other varying quantity.

[image]

The relation between a `cos` and a `sin` wave is only `pi/2` phase shift.

> cos(t) = sin(t + pi/2 );

What you only need to do to make your object move, is to vary `t` over time, inject it into the wave equation, and multiply your object possibly the `Y` position with the computed result from the wave equation.

Implementing this is straightforward

```
float initx = 0;
float inity = 0;
Object.x = initx+ time;
Object.y = inity+ (a * sin(2 * PI * f * t + phase));
```

But keep in mind that this will *not* simulate how an object would float on water. The topic would be much more complicated. This will only simulate a sine wave.