# Trying to make sprite float up and down

Tags: mathematics, physics, libgdx, box2d

Using LibGDX + Box2D and my understanding of the answer posted from this question: [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66129/how-to-move-an-object-up-and-down-like-a-wave)

I apply the following impulse:

```
// modify sprite's Box2d Body object
int a = 8; // amplitude
int f = 1; // frequency
int p = 1; // phase
float value = (float) ( a * Math.sin( 2 * Math.PI *f * TimeUtils.millis() + p ) );
body.applyLinearImpulse( 0, value, body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, false );

// render it
sprite.setPosition( body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y );
sprite.draw( spriteBatch );
```

But this just causes my sprite to go straight up and offscreen rather than doing a wave. What part of the algorithm am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you need to use smaller values for amplitude and frequency. Anyway you are using to calculate linear impulse. The function actually calculates the Y position of the object. you are using that Y value to apply an impulse, which will cause multiple impulses to cause the object to fly away. Then when Y is negated it will have the opposite force direction.

Comment: Thanks concept3d, your explanation was helpful. So if currently I'm calculating the Y position instead of the necessary impulse, how can I modify the formula so that it calculates the impulse instead?

Comment: it depends on what are you trying to achieve? You don't necessarily need this formula.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeUtils.millis()
```

Maybe you mean to do:

```
final long floatyPeriod = 3000; //3 secs
long now   = TimeUtils.millis();
long delta = lastTime - now;
lastTime = now;
object.floatyTime += delta;
if (object.floatyTime > floatyPeriod )
    object.floatyTime -= floatyPeriod;

...

float value = (float) ( amplitude * Math.sin( 2 * Math.PI * frequency * object.floatyTime/1000 + phase ) );
```

I don't understand how your code would make it go straight up though, I think it should wobble up and down like crazy with yours.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I got the idea of using the now time from [here](http://marksteve.com/dtmb/), specifically line 367 of [main](https://github.com/marksteve/dtmb/blob/gh-pages/main.js). Originally I was just modifying the body's Y coordinate like they did, but I changed to applying impulse instead because body.setTransform() doesn't render as smoothly.